# Is it possible to insert an image over other at a particular in space?

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, gd

Is it is possible to put one image over another image at a particular area using php & java script or any other libraries?  Also can the image be placed at a particular angle ?

I am developing a system where the user will upload an image and the image will be merged with the template uploaded by the admin from the administrator end. But I got stucked at a point where the image is not getting paste over the template at a particular angle automatically. The system is working well at http://182.71.22.42/srsandroidiphone/step_1.php?id=Ii1DJGAKYAo=

I am looking functionality like https://placeit.net/#!/stages/ipad-mini-and-iphone-6-mockup-template-of-a-young-man-at-the-garden-a4878

Comment: Yes you need to use layers (z-index could do), floats, and positioning values + a little bit of javascript.  Goodluck with that :)

Comment: @Dave Actually I was developing functionality like https://placeit.net/#!/stages/ipad-mini-and-iphone-6-mockup-template-of-a-young-man-at-the-garden-a4878..where the user will input the image and it will be fixed over the template created by the admin. But my problem here is that the front end user have to move the image to the specific are and also user have to rotate the image at some angles to fix it in template. Is there is any system or framework which can do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Placing an image over an other one is very easy in CSS. You could do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="image1.png" alt="" />
   <img src="image2.png" alt="" class="over" />
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.container { position: relative; }
.container .over { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; }
```

But in your case, this is a bit more difficult. I think the best way to day it would be to place the template image on top (with some transparency in it of course), and the image uplaoded by the user below it. That way, the cropping will be automatically made. It would be something like this :

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="image1.png" alt="" class="ontop" />
   <img src="image2.png" alt="" class="below" />
</div>
.container { position: relative; }
.container .ontop{ z-index: 2; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; }
.container .below{ z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; }
```

Then, you can work with css width and height properties to resize the image below. You can also use the transform property to rotate it.

```
.container { position: relative; }
.container .ontop{ z-index: 2; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; }
.container .below{ z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; transform: rotate(7deg); width: 100px; height: 50px; }
```

This will make the front end display. If you want the user to ba able to download the final image, you should work with canvas or the GD2 php library.

And of course, if you want this to be made automatically (I refer to your comment on your own post), you can use PHP to set CSS properties value:

```
<img src="image2.png" alt="" class="below" style="top: <?php echo getTopPosition(); ?>px;" />
```

Comment: Yes, I am doing it with canvas and GD library. but the skew transformations are not getting done properly. If template is at some angle then the images are not getting fixed correctly.

Comment: functionality like https://placeit.net/#!/stages/ipad-mini-and-iphone-6-mockup-template-of-a-young-man-at-the-garden-a4878

With only GD transformations